# Finding a TImage by its Tag property

Tags: c++builder, vcl, timage

I am using C++Builder and I have 64 `TImage` controls with different `Tag` values. Can I find an Image by its Tag somehow? I need this because my function has to move between two objects (which are Images) by adding 1 to their `Tag`s. I am using the VCL library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function available in the VCL to do this for you.  You will have to manually loop through the `Components[]` property of the owning `TForm`, or the `Controls[]` property of the `Parent` of the `TImage` controls, checking each component/control for `TImage` before accessing their `Tag`, eg:

```cpp
TImage* TMyForm::FindImageByTag(NativeInt ATag)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ComponentCount /* or: SomeParent->ControlCount */; ++i)
    {
        if (TImage *img = dynamic_cast<TImage*>(Components[i] /* or: SomeParent->Controls[i] */))
        {
            if (img->Tag == ATag)
                return img;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

```cpp
TImage *img = FindImageByTag(...);
if (img)
    img->Tag = img->Tag + 1;
```

Alternatively, you should store pointers to your `TImage` controls in your own array, which you can then index into/loop through when needed, eg:

```cpp
private:
    TImage* Images[64];

...

__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Images[0] = Image1;
    Images[1] = Image2;
    Images[2] = Image3;
    ...
    Images[63] = Image64;
}

TImage* TMyForm::FindImageByTag(NativeInt ATag)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
    {
        if (Images[i]->Tag == ATag)
            return Images[i];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

When populating the array, if you don't want to hard-code the 64 pointers individually, you can use a loop instead:

```cpp
__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    int idx = 0;
    for(int i = 0; (i < ComponentCount /* or: SomeParent->ControlCount */) && (idx < 64); ++i)
    {
        TImage *img = dynamic_cast<TImage*>(Components[i] /* or: SomeParent->Controls[i] */)
        if (img)
            Images[idx++] = img;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, using the Form's `FindComponent()` method:

```cpp
__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    int idx = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 64; ++i)
    {
        TImage *img = dynamic_cast<TImage*>(FindComponent(_D("Image")+String(i)));
        if (img)
            Images[idx++] = img;
    }
}
```